# Get historcial points ios

Tags: ios, drawing, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch

Is there any function or algorithm to catch all the points when drawing in `iPhone`? Like in Android, where we have gethistoical points.

Comment: Explain in details what you want. Also its better if you post what have you tried .

Comment: Actually we are devloping an application which shows remote desktop of the server which recieves mouse points from Ipad and performs annotationns/drawing. The same drawing is also performed on Ipad  so that user has a proper drawing experience with out delay. But the drawings in Ipad dont sync with the drawings on server. tkanzakic we are using the same logic to retrieve touch points. This woirks well when we perform slow annotations but when speed of performing annotation is increased,  all the touch points are not captured, hence not showing smooth annotations.

Comment: Viccari , I hope its clear now

Answer (score 0):

Check the methods `touchesBegan:withEvent:`, `touchesMoved:withEvent:`, `touchesEnded:withEvent:` and `touchesCancelled:withEvent:` to detect movements

For example using the method -touchesMoved:withEvent:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPosition = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(currentPosition));
}
```

For more info check the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html) of the UIResponder class

Comment: Actually we are devloping an application of drawing in ipad which simulataniously represented in server (ie PC). So when drawing fast its appearing as two lines with a small gap over there. How to over come this?

Comment: Actually we are devloping an application which shows remote desktop of the server which recieves mouse points from Ipad and performs annotationns/drawing. The same drawing is also performed on Ipad  so that user has a proper drawing experience with out delay. But the drawings in Ipad dont sync with the drawings on server. tkanzakic we are using the same logic to retrieve touch points. This woirks well when we perform slow annotations but when speed of performing annotation is increased,  all the touch points are not captured, hence not showing smooth annotations.